# Hibernate 4 : Prevent related table data when retrieve data from particular table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have entities **Userentity** and **Role** with many-to-many relationship, which implemented by associate entity **RoleUserentity** breaking many-to-many into two one-to-many relationships.

> **Userentity** --> **RoleUserentity** <-- **Role**

As I remembered in Hibernate older versions, the query

> from **Userentity** where **userId**=1

returns a **Userentity** object with only data in **userentity** table, and it doesn't contain data from tables with relationship one-to-many (many-to-many) [have seen contains data from one-to-one and many-to-one].
To get data from one-to-many tables we have to write a join query

> select **u** from **Userentity u** inner join **u.roleUserentities ru** where **u.userId**=1

But as I see Hibernate 4 returns **Userentity** object with data from one-to-many tables (**RoleUserentity**) too for

> from **Userentity** where **userId**=1

This happens in both pure and Jpa implementations of Hibernate 4, I checked in many different ways.
This is easy for developers, but it's an unnecessary processing time and consumption when need data only from particular entity (**Userentity**).

So anyone know how to retrieve data only from particular entity, prevent data from other entities in Hibernate 4??? It's better if it has to set a simple property in hibernate configuration which applies to all entities and queries.

Entity classes generated by Netbeans IDE wizard. (First I caught up this case when working in Eclipse)
--- Userentity  ---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userentity")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Userentity.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Userentity u")})
public class Userentity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private short status;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userentity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<RoleUserentity> roleUserentityList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId")
    private List<Payment> paymentList;

    public Userentity() {
    }

    public Userentity(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Userentity(Integer userId, short status) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.status = status;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

--- RoleUserentity ---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role_userentity")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "RoleUserentity.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM RoleUserentity r")})
public class RoleUserentity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected RoleUserentityPK roleUserentityPK;
    @Column(name = "date_from")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateFrom;
    @Column(name = "date_to")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateTo;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private short status;
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Role role;
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Userentity userentity;

    public RoleUserentity() {
    }

    public RoleUserentity(RoleUserentityPK roleUserentityPK) {
        this.roleUserentityPK = roleUserentityPK;
    }

    public RoleUserentity(RoleUserentityPK roleUserentityPK, short status) {
        this.roleUserentityPK = roleUserentityPK;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public RoleUserentity(int roleId, int userId) {
        this.roleUserentityPK = new RoleUserentityPK(roleId, userId);
    }

// getters and setters         
}
```

--- Servlet code ---

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session s = factory.openSession();
Userentity u = (Userentity)s.createQuery("select u from Userentity u where u.userId=1").uniqueResult();
out.println(((RoleUserentity)u.getRoleUserentityList().get(0)).getRole().getName());
s.close();
```

In 3rd line I used s.get(), s.load(), furthermore earlier in Jpa EntityManager.findById(), then findOne() in Spring CrudRepository too. But still result is the same.

Comment: Don't mark the association as eager fetched. You posted no code at all, so we can't point you to where the error is.

Comment: Use `lazy fethcing` or may be use `projections `

Comment: I put lazy fetch to both **Userentity** and **RoleUserentity** sides. But still have the problem.

Comment: You're calling `u.getRoleUserentityList().get(0)`. So obviously, the list of RoleUserentity must be loaded at this time. How could hibernate give you the first element of the list if it doesn't load the list?

Comment: This case happens for **@OneToMany**, no effect for **@ManyToMany**. Also seems this happens in Hibernate 3.

Comment: fetchType=LAZY is the solution. It loads data from related tables on relevant method invocation with a second select query. Thanks to people who gave the correct solution, early I didn't understand this scenario.